# How to run and edit Jupyter Notebook Code in PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, data-science

How can we run Jupiter Notebook in PyCharm Community Edition? It says" Once a notebook is opened, you can view all of its cells with both input and outputs. Editing and cell execution are not allowed.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a virtual environment with the usual jupyter packages installed, you can do this:

1. Open a terminal, ensure your virtual environment is activated
2. Change directory to where your jupyter notebook is saved
3. Run command `jupyter notebook`

This starts a local notebook server and normally opens a browser to your current terminal directory. From there, you can open, create, edit and save notebooks.  The terminal window displays a link to the notebook server which is useful if you close your browser.

`Quit` in the original browser window to shutdown the server/stop the jupyter kernel.

Technically speaking, this is not running in PyCharm and certainly does not give access to PyCharm's debugging tools, but it does allow you to play with a notebook and keep changes under source control.

Tested with PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Community Edition).

Answer (score -1):

First You need to install the Jupyter Notebook Package.
And then create a IPYNB file and start doing.
Hope this would work for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).